# How do you set the time zone in Crashlytics?

Tags: android, crashlytics

How do you set the time zone in Crashlytics? It's showing in UTC now, and I don't see the setting that allows you to change it.

Comment: I don't think you can.  I'm not a fan of Crashlytics.  You can try Crittercism and set the timezone on a per app basis quite easily.

Comment: Note that UTC time uses winter time for those of us in the USA where we have Daylight Savings Time in the summer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Comment: Connect your crashlytics project with firebase, in firebase crashlytics you will get configured time zone

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For instance, there is no way to do that.

Today, I've received an email from Crashlytics' support team where they informed that this request is already on their roadmap. On the other hand, they still don't have any idea when this feature will be launched.

Comment: did anything change since then?

Comment: @LangustenGustel I sent an email to crashlytics team (right now) regarding this subject. As soon as I receive any answer, I'll update my post. Cheers

Comment: This is ridiculous.

Comment: Although part of the team were at Google I/O this week, one developer advocate replied my inquiry informing that they are still "considering ways to make this possible". To sum up, they did not provide any target date as well as they just mentioned that "community will like what they do over the next year". Anyway, if they get it done, I will keep you guys posted.

Comment: well, once you were acquired by a large company with loads of cash, what would be the motivation to fix "tiny" issues like this?

Comment: They were supposed to keep encouraging their users using Crashlytics, not implementing this feature wouldn't be the best way to achieve this goal though.

Comment: This is never going to happen. Fabric/Crashlytics is being discontinued in favour of Firebase so we are out of luck. :)

Comment: @RobertGummesson hopefully you are wrong because this functionality would be  extremely helpful for most of us ;) !